# MySQL Querying a movie database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm very new to SQL, so please bear with me.

I've built a movie database and I'm trying to query it so that all my tables display properly.

I have a `movies` table with the columns `movieID`, `title`, `releaseYear`, `directorID`, `genreID`, and `actorID`.

Inside the table `director`, I have `directorID` and `Director`.

Using the query `SELECT * FROM movies INNER JOIN director ON director.directorID = movies.directorID;`, I'm able to get everything in tables `movies` and `director` to display (which isn't exactly what I want, but it's in the right track).

My remaining tables are `actor`, (with actorID and actor's names) `starring` (with starringID, movieID, and actorID), `genre` (with genreID and 22 different genres), and `moviegenres` (with moviegenresID, moviesID, and genreID).

I'm a bit lost and I apologize if this is confusing and messy, but I'm thinking I need to query the database so that all the tables show the data and are associated with the correct column. For example, most movies have multiple genres and actors, which is why I separated them into tables of their own.

I can't figure out how to query everything to display properly in the result grid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A lot depends on how you are grouping the output data. You might want to provide an example of the desired output. It could be done in one query, or it may require several queries.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I want the output to list the `movieID`,`title`,`releaseYear`(all from table movies),`Director` (from table director),`genre`, and `actor`. 

In my `movies` table, I don't have anything in genreID or actorID because I don't quite understand how to go about adding multiple values. The way I understand it is that you can't do that, so you have to make a separate table, which is why I have `starring` and `moviegenres` where multiple actorIDs and genreIDs will point to one movieID.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the description if the output. You wouldn't put the linking info in the movies table. Since _many_ actors can be in _many_ movies, you would have a table to link them that has 3 columns: an id column, a foreign key to movies, and a foreign key to actors. Same thing for genres. For more info, google _many to many relationship sql_